# How to browse multiple csv file using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Could anyone please help me how I can browse multiple csv file using AngularJS?

While uploading file

```
Browse <input type="file" multiple accept="csv/*" file-model="browseFile"/>
```

Comment: check docs of ng-file-upload

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import) would help? I have no idea what your question is though.